# Ensure that a name (from user input) contains only letters

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a code that will check to see if the user's input is left blank or contains numbers. Also, I get an error for .empty?

```
    in `block in <main>': undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
loop do
  print "Please tell us your first name: "
  first_name = gets.chomp.capitalize!

  if first_name.empty? or first_name.nil?
    puts "No input. Please tell us your first name:"
  elsif first_name[0..-1].include?(0..9)
    puts "Numbers are an unacceptable character."
    puts "Please tell us your first name: "
  else
    break
  end
end
```

If this code is slow and/or verbose, I'd appreciate a hint for improvement. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the exception: the check for `.nil?` *must* come before the check for `.empty?`, because `nil.empty?` will raise an exception. As for why there was `nil` (and there is no reason to have one in this case), read [`String#capitalize!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21) .. and then fix the code by using `capitalize` instead, which also allows the `.nil?` check to be removed. Tidy. (Only use `mutate!` methods in the rare situations in which they *may* be beneficial, especially for strings.)

Comment: @user2864740 has nicely explained both the problem and the fix. Identically, sometimes you'll see the equivalent of `if first_name.nil? or first_name.empty?` written `if (first_name || '').empty?`.  This works because `nil || '' => ''`.

Comment: @user2864740, that's the answer to the question. Shouldn't be a comment IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) If input field empty，it will return `nil`, so you should check `nil` first.

```
1.9.3-p547 :046 > first_name = gets.chomp.capitalize!

=> nil
1.9.3-p547 :047 > first_name
=> nil
1.9.3-p547 :048 > nil.empty?
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

(2) To find out if name contains a number, a regular expression can be used. It has good extensibility.

```
1.9.3-p547 :053 > /[\d]/.match('jason123')
=> #<MatchData "1">
1.9.3-p547 :054 > /[\d]/.match('jason')
=> nil
```

`/[\d]/` represents any number. If name doesn't have number, it will return `nil`.

Comment: Input field empty doesn't return `nil`. It returns `"\n"`. The main problem is that he's using `capitalize!` instead of `capitalize`. Even if you fill in something, he will still get `nil` because of this.

Comment: I agree with you, but if fill in something, it is impossible to get nil.

Comment: You don't need the `[]` if there is only one thing in it. Just use `/\d/`

Comment: @Mischa,I didn't know /\d/ was a Ruby method. But still, why doesn't "first_name.string[0..-1].include?(0..9)" work?
Shouldn't '.string[0..-1]' check every letter of first_name? **And** ".include?(0..9)" should check if first_name includes any numbers...?